# How to update the value of the least value row with the value of the maximum value row using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has a combination of item_id and payment_id columns as a key.

Every two rows have the same item_id value.

This is how the table looks.

```
item_id  payment_id  amount
      1     140       1000
      1     141       3000

      2     141        500
      2     145        600

      3       4       4000
      3     735       9000
```

How to subtract the amount value of the least payment_id row from the amount value of the maximum payment_id row (of the two rows with the same item_id) using **MySQL**?

To clarify, this is how the table I want.

```
item_id  payment_id  amount
      1     140       1000
      1     141       2000 : 3000 - 1000

      2     141        500
      2     145        100 :  600 -  500

      3       4       4000 
      3     735       5000 : 9000 - 4000
```

Cheer!

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" or "second" duplicate, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Please clarify.  Also, clarify what you mean by "duplicate row".  I do not see any duplicates in the data you have provided.

Comment: How do you define "duplicate"? How do you define "first"? And what if you have more than one duplicate?

Comment: Guys not so fast with the close button,it\`s quite clear that first and second is given by `ORDER BY item_id,payment_id`

Comment: Why the amount `4000` changed to `7000`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Sorry for my mistake. The second table has already been fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the new amount with this query:

```
select p1.item_id, p1.payment_id, p1.amount - (
    select p0.amount
    from payments p0
    where p0.item_id    = p1.item_id
      and p0.payment_id < p1.payment_id
    order by p0.payment_id
    limit 1
) as new_amount
from payments p1
having new_amount is not null;
```

It will subtract the amount of the "last" row with the same `item_id` (if present).

You can then use that query in the UPDATE statement as derived table joined to your original table:

```
update payments p
join (
    select p1.item_id, p1.payment_id, p1.amount - (
        select p0.amount
        from payments p0
        where p0.item_id    = p1.item_id
          and p0.payment_id < p1.payment_id
        order by p0.payment_id
        limit 1
    ) as new_amount
    from payments p1
    having new_amount is not null    
) p1 using (item_id, payment_id)
set p.amount = p1.new_amount;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/DJD86481

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tt JOIN (SELECT item_id, MAX(payment_id) mp , (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY payment_id DESC),',',1) - SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY payment_id ),',',1))  maxdif FROM tt GROUP BY item_id) s  
ON tt.item_id=s.item_id
SET tt.amount =s.maxdif
WHERE tt.payment_id =s.mp AND  tt.item_id=s.item_id;



SELECT * FROM tt;
```

[See it working](http://rextester.com/NPTMB54800)